# SQL or SSIS Checking Stg Table vs History Table for Dupes

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis, bids

I am receiving transaction information from multiple different sources and it is all combined into a single staging table. The staging table that contains:

```
TransactionNumber (Not Unique)
TransactionAmount
TransactionDate
TransactionLocation
AccountNumber
UpdatedDate
FileName
```

I am wanting to use SQL or SSIS to check the stg table vs history to find dupes. The problem is my sources can resend the transactions multiple times. I want to create a table contain all transactions since my process has ran the day before and then remove dupes of transactions I already have in history (Same Amount, Date, Location, and Account Number). This table will be used to send out once per day. I am not really sure how to go about this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It seems that you have all the data in one table and you already know how to identify duplicates, so what exactly is your question? Are you unable to write a SQL query to delete the duplicates or do you have some other issue?

Comment: I have two tables a Staging Table and a History Table. I want to compare the the two and find transactions that are not duplicates. I am not sure to go about how to write the query. That is my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to delete rows in one table that exist in another one, you probably need something like this:

```
delete from
    dbo.Staging
where
    exists (
        select *
        from 
            dbo.History
        where 
            TransactionAmount = dbo.Staging.TransactionAmount and
            UpdatedDate = dbo.Staging.UpdatedDate and
            TransactionLocation = dbo.Staging.TransactionLocation and
            AccountNumber = dbo.Staging.AccountNumber
    )
```